# How to Crop image that displaying only in transparent area?

Tags: android, transparent, crop

in image you can show a frame which is fix. I want to crop part of image only showing in to transparent area of the frame. so how to find an transparent area of a frame ? and how to get only a behind image only showing into transparent area... ?

[image]

Comment: Why dont your just take ImageViews in a FrameLayout and put one over another, keep photo in backgroud imageview and Frame image on upper imageview..if you just want to show like the above snap..!

Comment: We have already tried this but it's working , we want to crop that inside the dashed shape so how i can do this.

Comment: okay Girish, I know there is one open project to crop, but it doest it Rectangularly, as we can do in defaul gallery app..but this is something like "Magic Tool of Photoshop"

Comment: @girishce26 Post the code you've tried using the method suggested by MKJParekh and what exactly is not working.

Comment: @girishce26 For me it seems I am not able to crop the image visible through the frame any how, i have no idea, but if you tell me what you want to do with that cropped portion, i may help.

Comment: we have already implemented Rectangular crop shape, but we want to crop manually shape like that dahsed area of image...

Answer (score 0):

Here just we take two image view between relative layout. First frame(above image-view in snap shoot) is fix and on button click-listener a second image which we adjust behind the frame a simple logic is here. Not much complicated.

But main things is that we want to transparent area of frame. Here frame is not as like above screenshot but whatever, like face or hands whatever, I predeclared so crop it(a frame transparent part )and put it in another image.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Browse gallery" >
</Button>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/Button01"
     >
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button01"
    android:background="@drawable/frame" >
</ImageView>
```